# Dynamic toggle in menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic, toggle

Hi i need help to add dynamic toggle in menu as  i did show in code i did for each individual when ever i add a new menu i need to write code again to make it toggle any one can help me?

This my jquery

```
jQuery("li#menu-item-1826 > a").after("<span  class='spy-toggle'>+</span>");
 jQuery("li#menu-item-1867 > a").after("<span  class='spy-toggle'>+</span>");
 jQuery("li#menu-item-345 > a").after("<span  class='spy-toggle'>+</span>");
 jQuery("li#menu-item-349 > a").after("<span  class='spy-toggle'>+</span>");
 jQuery("li#menu-item-2029 > a").after("<span  class='spy-toggle'>+</span>");
 jQuery("li#menu-item-2595 > a").after("<span  class='spy-toggle'>+</span>");

    jQuery(".spy-toggle").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().children(".sub-menu").toggle();
    jQuery(this).text( jQuery(this).text() == '+' ? "-" : "+");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery’s ‘on’ event handler to handle the click events.  This would mean the event fires even for elements that were dynamically added to the DOM.   More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.spy-toggle', function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().children(".sub-menu").toggle();
  jQuery(this).text( jQuery(this).text() == '+' ? "-" : "+");
});
```